Use .env variables in Keycloak Admin Console Client configuration
Checking Keycloak's default clients for a new realm, you can find this kind of value, for example, in security-admin-console, the Rool URL is ${authAdminUrl}. That translates to localhost:8080 in my development environment and to my production URL in production.
I want to do the same thing for my created clients. I want to set my root URLs in my .env file and use them in the Admin Console as the root URL for my clients. And then in production I'll have the production URLs in the .env file.
I know how to set env vars in the theme configuration (int the theme.properties file), but I cannot find how to set it for use in the Admin Console. Is there any way to do this?
I'm using keycloak in docker, if that makes any difference.
